# Javascript TinyMCE percent sign

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have some trouble with trying to put a text in TinyMCE.
"Capital Allowance can help you claim up to 50% back on furniture and furnishings as well as equipment used outside your property for maintenance. You could even claim up to 100% of the costs back for purchases that count as environmentally friendly."

It returns an empty string when I try to save it (this is not a database problem - the output of TinyMCE is empty).

When I try putting in a string like that:

"50% 100%", the output is: "500%".

"75% 100%", the output is: "750%".

If I try putting more than one space it works perfectly. Can someone explain to me the equation that TinyMCE or Javascript is doing on those strings?

Comment: Try to use &#37 instead of %

Comment: You need to provide more details on how you are getting data from TinyMCE.  See the following TinyMCE Fiddle:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DYfaab/1  When I click the button to show the editor contents it returns the data as I would expect.  I tried all the strings from your example and they all do what I expect.

Comment: Thank you for linking TinyMCE fiddle. I realized this is caused by combo of Codeigniter and TinyMCE, not by TinyMCE itself. I was checking output using codeigniter and $_POST, so I assumed that TinyMCE gives wrong data to output. TinyMCE data output was correct, but codeigniter was running input sanitization class. I disabled this lines of code in input.php(Codeigniter core files): "return ($xss_clean === TRUE)
   ? $this->security->xss_clean($value)
   : $value;"

Comment: Thank you for your time.